# Why do I get this error when I specify a path in the windows command prompt?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, python, ms-dos

I'm trying to use the `cd` command in order to point to the folder where my file is located but I keep getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` (see screenshot).

Could anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: P.s. I wasn't overly sure about the appropriate title/tags for this question, suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: You might want to add some additional detail around what you are trying to do, and with what language.

Answer (score 0):

You're entering the `cd` command within an instance of the python interactive interpreter (notice the `>>>` at the beginning of the lines), not within the windows command prompt.

Try exiting python with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After this, enter your `cd` command.

**Edit:**

Maybe you just want to run a python program? Then you would would have to run

```
python path\to\your\pythonfile.py
```

Comment: if I'd like to run multiple files from the same folder, then do I need to specify the full path each time? My `cd` command was an attempt to avoid that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, in the windows command prompt, change to the folder containing the python files with `cd`, the you can omit the full path; the filename is sufficient then: `python srcfile.py`.

Answer (score 0):

To complement @phoibos's answer, you are trying to change to a directory on another drive, you need to use the `/d` switch when in the normal cmd console.

```
cd /d D:\folder
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using `cd` in a Python environment, which is not available here. You should use `chdir` from `os` module to change the current working path in Python.

Also, you use backslashes for defining the path, which need to be escaped. Either use `D:\\back_this_up\\.....` or `D:/back_this_up/......`.

Example:

```
import os
os.chdir("D:/back_this_up/your/desired/path")
```

and then do whatever you want to do.

If you want to use `cd` (as you described in your question) you have to exit the Python interpreter with `exit()` command and then use the syntax you tried before.